# Side navigation html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a side-navigation with a dropdown list. But its not working.
I made a list with things that should dropdown but only half of the list actually drops down. I want everything to drop down and a scrollbar to appear so the menu is not too long.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```css
html {
  background-color: #CEF6F5;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

h {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  font-family: Castellar;
}

u1.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

#one {
  background-color: #F3F781;
  color: black;
  width: 850px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 1;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  float: right;
  border-style: double;
}

.a {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 313px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}

li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 100000px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#ten {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <title>
    Latijnse geschiedenis
  </title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <button class="accordion"><a href="#">Informatie</a> </button>
    <div class="panel">


      <tr id="two">
        <div id="left">
          <li>
            <a href="115.000.html">115.000 v.C</a>
            <a href="200.html">200</a>
            <a href="plaatje3.html">1652</a>
            <a href="plaatje4.html">1713</a>
            <a href="plaatje5.html">1779</a>
            <a href="plaatje6.html">1795</a>
            <a href="plaatje7.html">1803</a>
            <a href="1835.html">1835</a>
            <a href="1849.html">1849</a>
            <a href="1852.html">1852</a>
            <a href="1855.html">1855</a>
            <a href="1858.html">1858</a>
            <a href="1859.html">1859</a>
            <a href="1880.html">1880</a>
            <a href="1912.html">1912</a>
            <a href="1930.html">1930</a>
            <a href="1948.html">1948</a>
            <a href="1964.html">1964</a>
            <a href="1983.html">1983</a>
            <a href="1997.html">1997</a>
            <a href="2013.html">2013</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</span>

  <h>Tijdlijn van de geschiedenis van de Romeinen</h>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "313px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <ul class="img-list">
    <li>
      <a href="Aeneas.html">
        <img src="1.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span id= "ten">115.000 v.C</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2.html">
        <img src="2.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>200</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="3.html">
        <img src="3.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1652</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="4.html">
        <img src="4.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1713</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="5.html">
        <img src="5.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1779</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="6.html">
        <img src="6.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1795</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="7.html">
        <img src="7.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1803</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="8.html">
        <img src="8.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1835</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1849.html">
        <img src="1849.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1849</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1852.html">
        <img src="1852.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1852</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1855.html">
        <img src="1855.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1855</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1858.html">
        <img src="1858.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1858</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1859.html">
        <img src="1859.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1859</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1880.html">
        <img src="1880.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1880</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1912.html">
        <img src="1912.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1912</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1930.html">
        <img src="1930goed.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1930</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1948.html">
        <img src="1948.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1948</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1964.html">
        <img src="1964.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1964</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1983.html">
        <img src="1983.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1983</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1997.html">
        <img src="1997!.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1997</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2013.html">
        <img src="2013.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>2013</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should checkout this link : [CodePen : Menu](http://codepen.io/fusionPT/pen/GJOZJb)

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding of your question.

1) You need to add `overflow: scroll` for the `div that containing list items`.

2) You need to add `height:400px;` for the `div that containing list items`.

```
#left {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height:400px;  
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Other suggestion: You can just use `<ul id="#left">` instead of `<div id="#left">`

For better look change to:

1) Add `clear:both` to #left

```
#left {
      margin-left: 0px;
      height:400px;  
      overflow: scroll;
      clear: both;
    }
```

2) Remove `overflow-x: hidden` from .sidenav.

```css
span {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 313px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}

li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

#left {
  margin-left: 0px;
  height:400px;  
  overflow-y: scroll;
  clear: both;
}

#ten {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <button class="accordion"><a href="#">Informatie</a> </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <tr id="two">
        <ul id="left">
          <li>
            <a href="115.000.html">115.000 v.C</a>
            <a href="200.html">200</a>
            <a href="plaatje3.html">1652</a>
            <a href="plaatje4.html">1713</a>
            <a href="plaatje5.html">1779</a>
            <a href="plaatje6.html">1795</a>
            <a href="plaatje7.html">1803</a>
            <a href="1835.html">1835</a>
            <a href="1849.html">1849</a>
            <a href="1852.html">1852</a>
            <a href="1855.html">1855</a>
            <a href="1858.html">1858</a>
            <a href="1859.html">1859</a>
            <a href="1880.html">1880</a>
            <a href="1912.html">1912</a>
            <a href="1930.html">1930</a>
            <a href="1948.html">1948</a>
            <a href="1964.html">1964</a>
            <a href="1983.html">1983</a>
            <a href="1997.html">1997</a>
            <a href="2013.html">2013</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</span>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "313px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_sidenav_shift

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<nav class="w3-sidenav w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="display:none" id="mySidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
  onclick="w3_close()"
  class="w3-closenav w3-large">Close &times;</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</nav>

<div id="main">

<header class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <span class="w3-opennav w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()" id="openNav">&#9776;</span>
  <h1>My Header</h1>
</header>

<img src="img_car.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>In this example, the sidenav is hidden (style="display:none") and is only shown when you click on the menu icon in the top left corner. When it is opened, it shifts the page content to the right (we use JavaScript to add a 25% left margin to the div element with id="main" when this happens. The value "25%" matches the value used to set the width of the sidenav. Tip: If you change the left margin to 40%, you should change the width of the sidenav to 40% as well.</p>
</div>

<footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h5>Footer</h5>
  <p>Footer information goes here</p>
</footer>

</div>

<script>
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'none';
}
function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-height` in div.panel and div.panel.show. Changed `display: fixed`. Now its working. Compare your code to find it.

```css
html {
  background-color: #CEF6F5;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  color: black;
}

h {
  color: black;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  font-family: Castellar;
}

u1.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

#one {
  background-color: #F3F781;
  color: black;
  width: 850px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 1;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  float: right;
  border-style: double;
}

.a {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 313px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 100000px;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#ten {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <title>
    Latijnse geschiedenis
  </title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <button class="accordion"><a href="#">Informatie</a> </button>
    <div class="panel">


      <tr id="two">
        <div id="left">
          <li>
            <a href="115.000.html">115.000 v.C</a>
            <a href="200.html">200</a>
            <a href="plaatje3.html">1652</a>
            <a href="plaatje4.html">1713</a>
            <a href="plaatje5.html">1779</a>
            <a href="plaatje6.html">1795</a>
            <a href="plaatje7.html">1803</a>
            <a href="1835.html">1835</a>
            <a href="1849.html">1849</a>
            <a href="1852.html">1852</a>
            <a href="1855.html">1855</a>
            <a href="1858.html">1858</a>
            <a href="1859.html">1859</a>
            <a href="1880.html">1880</a>
            <a href="1912.html">1912</a>
            <a href="1930.html">1930</a>
            <a href="1948.html">1948</a>
            <a href="1964.html">1964</a>
            <a href="1983.html">1983</a>
            <a href="1997.html">1997</a>
            <a href="2013.html">2013</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰</span>

  <h>Tijdlijn van de geschiedenis van de Romeinen</h>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "313px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <ul class="img-list">
    <li>
      <a href="Aeneas.html">
        <img src="1.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span id= "ten">115.000 v.C</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2.html">
        <img src="2.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>200</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="3.html">
        <img src="3.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1652</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="4.html">
        <img src="4.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1713</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="5.html">
        <img src="5.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1779</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="6.html">
        <img src="6.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1795</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="7.html">
        <img src="7.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1803</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="8.html">
        <img src="8.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1835</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1849.html">
        <img src="1849.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1849</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1852.html">
        <img src="1852.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1852</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1855.html">
        <img src="1855.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1855</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1858.html">
        <img src="1858.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1858</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1859.html">
        <img src="1859.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1859</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1880.html">
        <img src="1880.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1880</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1912.html">
        <img src="1912.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1912</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1930.html">
        <img src="1930goed.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1930</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1948.html">
        <img src="1948.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1948</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1964.html">
        <img src="1964.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1964</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1983.html">
        <img src="1983.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1983</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="1997.html">
        <img src="1997!.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>1997</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="2013.html">
        <img src="2013.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>2013</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```